# Oracle: Commit pending transactions on slow table

Tags: oracle, commit, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have an Oracle table in which I tried to insert a huge number of records (about 150M).
I was using sqldeveloper, and I did not click the 'commit' button after my inserts.

Now the table is veeery slow on any operations, but if I do an update or a count, it shows the table has 0 records.  Example, an update on all records took 5 hours and it updates 0 records.

So I figure that the reason why it is slow is because there are uncommitted transactions on it.  How do I commit any on these pending transactions?  (SqlDeveloper has been closed and opened after the initial inserts).

Comment: :Your sqldeveloper is been closed ,that means your session is been expired, and that means all the initial insert is rollback :(,No other way to retrieve the pending transactions .Try fresh insert

Comment: Thanks.  I expected that, but why is the table so slow?  Obviously something must be in there?

Comment: :WHat is the count in the table?

Comment: It is zero, but running the count takes a very long time.

Answer (score 3):

You have probably no indexes on that table, thus you must run full table scans.
And table's "high watermark" was moved forward.
Try to reduce size on table's segment by executing "alter table shrink space compact".
Or you can use "old-fashioned" command "alter table move", but this one will invalidate your table's indexes and those have to be rebuild too.

Note: Oracle tables are not self-defragmenting.

Comment: You are correct there are no indexes.  But having 0 records my thinking was that a count should still be quick.  Thanks for the advice.

Comment: When you inserted 150M of rows in that table Oracle extended table's space allocation unit "SEGMENT". This was not reduced when our transaction was rolled back. As there are no indexes Oracle does not know that there are in fact no rows in it. It has to scan the whole segment every time you access the table.

Comment: Thanks Ivan.  It does make sense.  Prabably just easiet to dump the table and start with a new one.

Answer (score 0):

If you have necessary priviliges you can use

```
    select    nvl(S.USERNAME,'Internal') username,
                nvl(S.TERMINAL,'None') terminal,
                L.SID||','||S.SERIAL# Kill,
                U1.NAME||'.'||substr(T1.NAME,1,20) tab,
                decode(L.LMODE,1,'No Lock',
                               2,'Row Share',
                               3,'Row Exclusive',
                               4,'Share',
                               5,'Share Row Exclusive',
                               6,'Exclusive',null) lmode,
                decode(L.REQUEST,1,'No Lock',
                               2,'Row Share',
                               3,'Row Exclusive',
                               4,'Share',
                               5,'Share Row Exclusive',
                               6,'Exclusive',null) request
                from      V$LOCK L,
                V$SESSION S,
                SYS.USER$ U1,
                SYS.OBJ$ T1
    where  L.SID = S.SID
    and        T1.OBJ# = decode(L.ID2,0,L.ID1,L.ID2)
    and        U1.USER# = T1.OWNER#
    and        S.TYPE != 'BACKGROUND'
order by 1,2,5
```

this sql gives you any lock in table , you can kill them

Comment: This query gives me some results, but I can't see the specified table in that list.

Comment: which means there is no lock on your table than maybe u have problem in your sql.

Answer (score 0):

Your table may be locked, Please run the below query from system user to find out is there any lock on that table.

```
select
  object_name, 
  object_type, 
  session_id, 
  type,                 -- Type or system/user lock
  lmode,        -- lock mode in which session holds lock
  request, 
  block, 
  ctime                 -- Time since current mode was granted
from
  v$locked_object, all_objects, v$lock
where
  v$locked_object.object_id = all_objects.object_id AND
  v$lock.id1 = all_objects.object_id AND
  v$lock.sid = v$locked_object.session_id
ORDER BY
  session_id, ctime desc, object_name;
```

Comment: No locks on that table.  I can actually rename the table as well.